# VS Code main window is blank

Tags: visual-studio-code

Yesterday I downloaded the last version of VS Code and installed it.

When I launched it, at first, it seems to work fine, I went directly to the extension sections in order to check and download some, then I tried to change the sorting options to see the recommended extensions and then it was when the first symptom appeared. I clicked the button and nothing happened, I clicked it several times and after a while, the window for selecting the type of sorting appeared several times too (possible once for each time I clicked the button). I chose the recommended extensions, and no extension appeared.

I closed it and reopened it again, but this time, the main window was completely blank (actually, black). I restarted the PC, uninstalled the application, run CCleaner to clear the registry, reinstalled the application, all of that several times and nothing.

Sometime, after a long time running, it shows the usual sections, but when I close it and reopen it again, everything is the same.
Also, some options from the tool windows doesn't work, while other do (like the about window).

I've checked this FAQ:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_vs-code-main-window-is-blank
but the solution there didn't work neither.

I had a previous version of vscode that worked great. Sadly, I cannot remember which one was, not even a close guest and I removed it when I noticed that installing this new version didn't removed it.

This is how VS Code looks like when I open it:
[image]

This is the about window:
[image]

This is a snapshot of the task manager a few seconds after vscode is launched:
[image]

And these are my computer properties:
[image]

Did anyone experience a simmilar situation before? Does anyone know how to fix it?

---

**UPDATE 1**

When I installed this new version, I noticed that it didn't remove the previous version of the application that was installed (and working).
(This version instead of living on ProgramFiles was living on my User folder, I think on the Local AppSettings)

Then I proceed to uninstall it but stupidly missed the install entry at "Program and Features" and thought it wasn't registered there then I went to see if I could see an uninstaller, which I missed too. The rest of the story is obvious, because I though having these two versions was the problem I was determined to remove this last one and did it by manually deleting the folder, cleaning the registry, etc...

I'm writing this because, maybe, this old version left behind some configuration or registry information that would have been removed if I had followed the correct approach and, although my efforts to manually remove any trail, this is causing the new version to malfunction.
For example, I still have the option on the explorer's context menu to open a file with Code, this option belongs to the old version and when clicked, the error message: "Application Not found" is shown.

Comment: I would try renaming your `.vscode` directory in your user profile to something (.e.g., `.vscode.bak`). This would cause VS Code to re-initialize preferences and load without any extensions, etc.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: It didn't work neither. Sorry. Anyway, this is a fresh install, so I don't have any extensions nor I have modified any preference. Also, I had manually removed this folder too as an attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: You should also rename/delete the `AppData\Roaming\Code` directory in your user profile.

Answer (score 49):

To fix this for VS Code 1.18 (8 November 2017)

Right-click on Shortcut and add --disable-gpu to Target:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem with Version 1.24.1. Using "--disable-gpu" solved it. (Looks like it is a problem of the Electron shell: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_vs-code-is-blank)

Comment: This does not help at all.

Comment: This did help me on Windows 10 and VS Code v1.53.2

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem in windows 7,have resolved by following above 2 steps:

1.Right-click on VS Code Shortcut -> go to properties -> add --disable-gpu to Target:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu

2.setting the compatibility with windows 7 in VsCODE shortcut properties.

Answer (score 8):

Try changing the compatibility mode of VS code. Please find the illustrated image [image: here]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in windows 10, and it was resolved by setting the compatibility with windows 8 in VsCODE shortcut.

[image]

The image above is in Portuguese, please translate to your language.

Comment: Works for my case: using Win10 upgraded from Win7.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this, follow these steps:

1. Right-click on `Visual studio code` Shortcut.
2. Click on properties.
3. Go to shortcut tab.
4. Add `--disable-gpu` to `Target`.

It will look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu
```

Comment: its work for me. Any harm for using this command?

Answer (score 3):

I have same VS code black out issue.
In command prompt(cmd) run below command
"code --disable-gpu"

working for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Use both `--disable-gpu` `--disable-software-rasterizer`

Answer (score 2):

I have added `--disable-gpu` in shortcut's target tab but still it was not working and then tried to reinstalling the `vscode` but still no luck.

So **in my case problem was my antivirus**, it was quarantining the file `workbench.desktop.main.js` of `vscode` which is needed while running the program, so therefore it was not running and was showing black screen,

**So i have excluded the parent folder of that `workbench.desktop.main.js` file** which was `workbench`folder and reinstalled the `vscode` now it is running perfectly as it was.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode worked great for me, but at some point something broke and it showed only a blank black screen. That is, the problem was clearly not in the GPU. By brute force, I determined that the cause was a violation of the file `%AppData%\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb`

I removed it and VSCode worked like new.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting %appdata%\Code\User directory fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced it too recently on a win8.1 os.
It happened because i wrongly setted the gpu card as the default one for running visual studio code.
A **partial solution** is to disable the gpu card by adding `--disable-gpu` (as previously suggested) by Right-clicking on VS-Code Shortcut on your `desktop -> properties -> add` `--disable-gpu` to `Target` field:

`"C:\....your path ..\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu`

By doing so *it fixes the problem only if u launch the program by that shortcut icon*.
On the other hand, suppose u browse your file system and let's say you navigate into a  project folder.
Once inside it, *if you right click and select "open with code" ..the blank window will be shown again.*

So, since in my case i have an Nvidia Card i run the **Nvidia control panel** from where u can check your global settings and specific settings.
Under the global settings, set "automatic selection" as preferred graphic processor.
Also check the other tab too "program setting" and see if u added there visual studio code and if the gpu card was chosen. If yes..well disable it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was after I added a new folder.

parameter disable-gpu didn't work.

So, I removed directory "code" from "roaming" and I found again VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click > Visual Studio Properties

Add --disable-gpu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for this answer, but unfortunately nothing worked above mentioned answers. So here is my answer:

- I uninstalled the VS code completely from my machine following steps from this link: https://debug.to/1074/how-to-uninstall-vs-code-completely#:%7E:text=1%20Go%20to%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20path.%20%25LocalAppData%25%5CPrograms%5CMicrosoft,the%20.vscode%20folder%20at%20the%20below%20path%20%25UserProfile%25
- I then disabled my anti-virus software. In my case, it was Quick Heal security (expired).
- I installed the VS Code again on my machine, and IT WORKED!

I have been looking into this issue since 3 days! And finally, I am happy that it is working.

Answer (score -1):

Installing directx works for me =)