# VSCode freezes and stops responding

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-8

I had used VSCode in my previous Windows 7 system but now I am using a Windows 8 computer. so I installed VSCode. It ran well the first time but since then it opens then it would freeze with a blank screen. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling but nothing changed. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, after much search and time-wasting, I found my solution at [VS Code main window is blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323190/vs-code-main-window-is-blank). I was so glad that all I had to do was change compatibility mode to windows vista.