# Visual Studio Code not working, shows blank page

Tags: visual-studio-code

I run the Visual Studio Code in the morning, but it shows blank page. It worked fine yesterday. I am using iMac and Visual Studio Code version is 1.50.1.

[image]

Have anyone got this kind of experience before?

Comment: Is this what you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323190/vs-code-main-window-is-blank?

Answer (score 3):

Try relaunch Vscode again, or restart  your pc