# Can somebody help me with this vscode setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

can somebody help me please...?
since I update my visual studio code,
I can always see this strange blank.. and I can't close it in settings...
How can I close this..

Comment: Please do not tag Visual Studio for a VS Code question.

Comment: I hope you solve your problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323190/vs-code-main-window-is-blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323190/vs-code-main-window-is-blank)

Comment: I try to download again but it was still like this..

Comment: Did you perhaps enter "Centered layout" by accident? This is a new feature (and threw me off for a good while aswell when I accidentally activated it). You can deactive it by toggling View -> Appearance -> Centered layout

Comment: @phuzi sorry It's my mistake.. I have deleted tag and It's my first time to ask question in stackoverflow.. I will be careful next time .

Comment: @batuhanilgarr I try to download again but it was still like this... But thank you!

Comment: @nbokmans I see I deactivate it but i still can see the that blank. But thanks for  your suggestion!

Comment: Are you on a mac?  If so , possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916668/why-are-there-grey-spaces-on-the-vs-code-editor-window

Comment: @Mark Thankyou!! I deal with this problem!!